# How to close JMeter IDE from shell script?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a shell script deploying the utility jar file and starting the JMeter with the last test plan.  Now I would like to close any existing JMeter IDEs before the deployment.

Ideally, the script should invoke the IDE's save menu before closing the GUI.
This will avoid losing any unsaved work.

**Note**
Killing the JMeter's process may not work in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how this question is connected to JMeter.

It sounds like you're looking for a desktop automation tool like [Appium](https://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/windows/), [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-windows-applications-using-taurus-and-selenium-a-guide), [Sikuli](http://sikulix.com/), [LDTP](https://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/), etc.

It might be the case that you "shell" script can also send "Save" signal to running JMeter instances and close them, however it depends on the operating system and "shell" type.